# Допустимо ли говорить "...в процессе деятельности"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Есть ли какие-либо нарушения норм русского языка в употреблении выражения ***"...в процессе деятельности"***?
Другими словами, можно ли так говорить?

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, можно, если позволяет контекст. Например:

> В процессе своей деятельности на посту президента г-н
>   такой-то принял два весьма ответственных решения.

В этом примере "в процессе" (= в ходе, за время) лишь указывает на отдельные моменты в промежутке времени, когда человек работал президентом (= действовал как президент, выполнял обязанности президента); часть его работы оказалась связанной с принятием упомянутых решений. В контексте же, где "процесс" и "деятельность" полностью совпадают во времени и по содержанию, можно говорить о *тавтологии*, например: *В процессе своей деятельности он руководствовался принципами...* (вместо "в своей деятельности").

Answer (score 1):

[**процесс**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81), -а; м. [от лат. *processus* — течение, ход]
**<В процессе** *чего, **в значении предлога.*** Во время, в ходе чего-либо. *Новые идеи рождаются в процессе творчества.*

[**деятельность**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C), -и; ж.

1. Работа, занятие кого-либо в какой-либо области. *Педагогическая, научная, общественная деятельность. Деятельность по распространению юридических знаний. Кипучая деятельность. Деятельность в области экономики. Жажда деятельности.*
2. *Чего* или *какая*. О действии сил природы, работе каких-либо органов и т. п. *Деятельность ветра. Деятельность вулкана. Изучать деятельность мозга. Разрушительная деятельность воды*.

*В процессе деятельности* — такое сочетание можно употреблять только в том случае, если "в процессе" выполняет роль предлога (подразумевается значение *во время, в ходе, в течение*).

М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин ("За рубежом", 1881):

> Возьмите самые простые сельскохозяйственные задачи, предстоящие культурному человеку, решившемуся посвятить себя деревне, каковы, например: способы пользоваться землею, расчеты с рабочими, степень личного участия в прибылях, привлечение к этим прибылям батрака и т. п. — разве все это не находится в самой несносной зависимости от каких-то волшебных веяний, сущность которых даже не для всякого понятна? *А между тем эти веяния пристигают человека и в самом процессе его деятельности, и во всех последствиях этого процесса.*

[В словаре Даля: ***пристигать,** пристичь, пристигнуть* — настигать, достигать, на(до)гонять. *Ночь пристигла нас в лесу. Беда пристигла.*]

[Личность в процессе деятельности и общения](http://lib.mgppu.ru/OpacUnicode/app/webroot/index.php?url=/notices/index/IdNotice:14909/Source:default) (К. А. Абульханова-Славская, учебное пособие)

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос оказался сложнее, чем показалось. Что такое "процесс деятельности" и чем он отличается от просто "деятельности"?!

Формальных причин для запрета я не нашел. Но в тоже время выглядит избыточным, едва ли не тавтологией, и "канцеляритом". Деятельность - сама по себе процесс. Получается "в процессе процесса". Такое было бы вполне нормальным, будь этот "второй" процесс чем-то конкретным ("процесс пищеварения", "процесс познания"), тогда "первый" процесс обозначает протяженность содержательного понятия во времени и устанавливает некие его рамки. С этих позиций (субъективын) "процесс деятельности" выглядит стилистической  небрежностью. Вот как-то так...

А есть контекст, где такое сочетание было бы необходимым?!

Comment: *>> Что такое "процесс деятельности" и чем он отличается от просто "деятельности"?!* А тем, г-н @behemothus, что "в процессе деятельности" сказать с грехом пополам можно, а вот "в деятельности" – ну никак. *>> Вопрос оказался сложнее, чем показалось.* Поиск сложностей – наше всё.

Comment: Почему же **ну никак** нельзя сказать "в деятельности"? Посмотрите в Нацкорпусе: https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%B2+%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8